# Ionic app freezes and display a blank white screen when I launch it in airplane mode. what is happening?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

The app works fine under other conditions but if I am in airplane mode when I start the app it shows the blank white screen. Any help is appreciated.

app.js

```
    var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ionic', 'ngIOS9UIWebViewPatch', 'angular.filter', 'firebase', 'ngMask', 'yaru22.angular-timeago','myapp.controllers', 'myapp.directives', 'ngCordova', 'myapp.factories'])

myapp.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $timeout, $cordovaDialogs, $cordovaNetwork, $cordovaStatusbar, $cordovaSplashscreen, $ionicLoading, $state, Auth, $cordovaDatePicker, MembersFactory) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
            StatusBar.style(1)
        }
    }, 300);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you index.html / entry page, you probably referring third party dependencies of css and javascript from some external links.

Resolution :

1) if you have any cdn / http link there for css or javascript
2) Download those files and save it in your project itself
3) Test your app again